# chmod: changing permissions of 'bin': Operation not permitted

Tags: chmod

"bin" is the name of an empty folder on a Linux system that I want to delete.  From the parent folder, I have typed:

chmod 700 bin

And it returns

chmod: changing permissions of 'bin': Operation not permitted.

Answer (score 3):

Probably the file has the immutable flag set in its extended attributes.
To fix this, just run sudo chattr -i file

```
% sudo chattr -i immutable
% sudo chown user:user immutable
```

Comment: Thank you! This is the only solution on Azure for the unable to access the mounted disk `cloudfiles -> /mnt/batch/tasks/shared/LS_root/mounts/clusters/<your_machine_name>/` issue. Need to do 1. `sudo su - root`; 2. `sudo chattr -i /mnt`; `sudo chmod +x /mnt`

Answer (score 0):

it means you dont have permission for it.
check that whoami and after that check that who is owner of bin folder.

Answer (score 0):

Become su [switch user command]
In my case, I had a remote server with user temproot in it.
I used
su temproot
sudo -i
chmod 777 TargetDirectory or FileName